# JS doesn't get value from input

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

The problem is that I can't get value of my password fields - alert with pso1 returns null. 
 
I don't see any error in this code so I'm asking for help.

```
<form class='container' onsubmit="return checkit()">
    <h1> Javascript </h1>
    Login <input type='text' id='log'><br>
    Password <input type='password' id='pso1'><br>
    Confirm passwordd <input type='password' id='pso2'><br>
    <button>Register</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var pso1=document.getElementById('pso1').value ; 
    var pso2=document.getElementById('pso2').value ;    
    alert(pso1);
    function checkit(){
        if(pso1=!pso2){ 
            return false;
            alert('Passwords are not the same.');
        }
        else{
            return true; 
            alert('work');
        }
    }

</script>   

</body>
```

Comment: You're setting the value of the variables outside of the function, when the page loads.

Comment: Putting `alert()` after `return` won't work. `return` leaves the function and nothing after that executes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are setting the values of `pso1` and `ps02` once right after the page load before their values are changed. You will want to update these values instead, declared them as local variables inside your function:

```
function checkit(){
    var pso1=document.getElementById('pso1').value; 
    var pso2=document.getElementById('pso2').value;   
    if(pso1=!pso2){ 
        return false;
        alert('Passwords are not the same.');
    }
    else{
        return true; alert('work');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have only declared the function checkIt. You need to call that function to actually check it.

Comment: He's calling it here: `<form class='container' onsubmit="return checkit()">`

Comment: You should delete your answer if it's not relevant.