# How to get the input value for javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently trying to get the input field's value of what the user chose as their number but i'm unable to for some reason.

I've already tried making it an id and then doing `document.getElementById("testing").value` but it didn't work.

Here's my current code:

```html
<section class="generate">
  <div class="container">
    <h3>Generate a number between </h3>
    <form>
      First number
      <input id="testing" type="number" name="firstnumber" value="First number">
      <br> Second number
      <input type="number" name="secondnumber" value="Second number">
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Generate random number">
      <script>
        var secondNumber = document.getElementById('testing').value
        var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * secondNumber);
        console.log(randomNumber);
        console.log(secondNumber);
      </script>
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Your code is running when the page first loads, not after the user enters something in the input field. Put the code in an event listener.

Comment: Currently, it is only being calculated on load. You need to add `onsubmit` to the form or `onclick` to the button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JS doesn't get value from input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39540833/js-doesnt-get-value-from-input)

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the code in an event listener, not when the page first loads.

```js
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent form from really submitting
  var secondNumber = document.getElementById('testing').value
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * secondNumber);
  console.log(randomNumber);
  console.log(secondNumber);
});
```

```html
<section class="generate">
  <div class="container">
    <h3>Generate a number between </h3>
    <form>
      First number
      <input id="testing" type="number" name="firstnumber" value="First number">
      <br> Second number
      <input type="number" name="secondnumber" value="Second number">
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Generate random number">
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<section class="generate">
  <div class="container">
    <h3>Generate a number between </h3>
    <form onsubmit="return false">
      First number
      <input id="firstnumber" type="number" name="firstnumber" >
      <br> Second number
      <input id="secondnumber" type="number" name="secondnumber" >
      <br>
      <input type="submit" onclick="generate()" value="Generate random number">
      <script>
  function generate(){
        var firstnumber = document.getElementById('firstnumber').value
         var secondnumber =document.getElementById('secondnumber').value
        var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * secondnumber);
        console.log(randomNumber);
        console.log(firstnumber);
        console.log(secondnumber);}
      </script>
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```